# Django ORM: Select query when I instantiate a new Object

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have these models:

```
class Alarm(ModelWithValidation):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    value = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    reading = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                                     null=True,
                                     blank=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)


class SolarMeterReading(ModelWithValidation):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    irradiance = RoundedDecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2,
                                     null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=30)
    alarms = GenericRelation(Alarm)
```

I noticed that when I instatiate a SolarMeterReading Django makes a SELECT query:

```
SolarMeterReading(name='test', alarms=[])
```

Query:

```
SELECT "api_alarm"."id", "api_alarm"."datetime", 
"api_alarm"."value", "api_alarm"."description", 
"api_alarm"."content_type_id", 
"api_alarm"."object_id" FROM "api_alarm" WHERE 
("api_alarm"."object_id" IS NULL AND "api_alarm"."content_type_id" = 18);
```

Why does Django make this query? 
There's no reason to search for the related alarms if the SolarMeterReading is not yet saved on the database.

Comment: Try removing `alarms=[]`.

Comment: Yes, if i remove `alarms=[]` django doesn't make the query. But the question is more about why does django make it if the object is not yet saved on the db, in my opinion that query is useless.

Comment: I think you're looking at this the wrong way. You don't need to do `alarms=[]`, I'm not even sure whether it's a documented API. Direct assignment to reverse foreign keys and many-to-many fields was deprecated in [Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.10/#features-deprecated-in-1-10), I don't think you should be doing it for generic relation.

Comment: Ok, but actually i need to instantiate a fake `SolarMeterReading` with empty  `alarms` and i need to pass it to a `SolarMeterReading` serializer.
If i simply remove `alarms=[]` the query is runned anyway when the serializer try to access to `alarm` field.
Also using `set()` method with Django 1.10 the query is runned.
Thank you very much for help!

Comment: You might get a better response if you update your question with more information about what you are actually trying to achieve.